# Where can I find a time range widget in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, widget

I'm looking for some sort of TimeRange widget in Javascript/CSS/jQuery.  I'm not looking for a time/date picker, which are widely available.

I need it for a website to allow businesses to select their openinghours by clicking and hovering over the hours they're open.

```
+-----------------------------+
| 0h 0h15m 0h30m    ... 23:45 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Anybody has seen such a nice looking customizable timerange selector widget?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look for a slider widget.. then set the times you need as the intervals.

The jQuery UI has one:  [jQuery UI Slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider).

**Update:** based on the comment below about (single vs. double slider)...

1.) Theres a post already (just found) about making a [2 handled slider using the jQuery UI slider here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348187/jquery-slider-range).

Or if you have 2 sliders... one for opening time and one for closing... where each is broken down into 15min segments, but only for half a day each, would this work?

e.g. (ignore the ASCII-graphic uglyness)

```
 Open Time (AM): 12   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 |  9    10   11   12
                                                           ^ 8:15am

Close Time (PM): 12   1    2    3    4    5    6  |  7    8    9    10   11   12
                                                  ^6:30pm
```

Furthermore, if this is for "typical" businesses... you could likely chop from 11pm <-> 5am from the sliders.

Or,

I'm not a big fan of scriptaculous, but they seem to have a [double slider](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/slider):

Comment: I thought about that as well, but that wouldn't really work as we don't know how many regions there are from the start.  Eg. A business could be open from 8am-10am, 12-14am and 18-20am.  Moreover, as I understand from the documentation, there's a max of  one range per slider it seems.

This is an example I found with ticks: http://jsbin.com/iwime

Comment: Thanks scunliffe, I'm resorting to this not-so-flexible solution, until a widget emerges!

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar has nice one (you can see it when you click "Check guest and resource availability" link on the event details form). But I can imagine it would be hard to clone.

[image: Google Calendar Time Ranage]
<sub>(source: [rajchel.pl](http://stuff.rajchel.pl/stackoverflow/GoogleCalendarTimeRange.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot!  That's exactly what I'm looking for, in a more compact form.   I can't image it doesn't already exist, eg. as a pluggable jQuery widget.

Answer (score 1):

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

go to " Show only the time picker without date picker" and check if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/index.html

Demos here [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html) and here [Technical demo](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/technicalDemo.html)

> jQRangeSlider is open source published under dual license GPL and MIT.
>   You can use it in both open source and **commercial** software.

```
Prerequisites:
    jQuery
    jQuery UI Core
    jQuery UI Widget
    jQuery mousewheel plugin (optional)
```