# need a jquery time entry widget for an HTML form

Tags: html, webforms

I'm looking for a nice HTML form widget that makes it easy to enter a start time and an end time.  Any recommendations?

Thanks,
Graham

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131296/where-can-i-find-a-time-range-widget-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2):

There's [`jquery.timepickr.js`](http://haineault.com/media/examples/jquery-utils/demo/ui-timepickr.html).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks - Just found that - here's wiki page for it - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/UiTimepickr

appears to work w/ jquery UI themes.

Answer (score 0):

looks like IE it doesn't work in IE 6 or 7.  bummer ... really nice widget